# How to sort a LinkedHashMap by value in decreasing order in java stream?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, linkedhashmap

To sort it int ascending order I can use:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

How can I do it in decreasing order?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To sort in reverse order, pass `Comparator.reverseOrder()` as parameter to `comparingByValue`.

To get a `LinkedHashMap`, you must specifically request one with the 4-argument `toMap()`.  If you don't specify what kind of a map you want, you will get whatever the default is, which currently happens to be a `HashMap`.  Since `HashMap` doesn't preserve the order of elements, it will definitely not do for you.

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                (x,y)-> {throw new AssertionError();},
                LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
```

With static imports, it becomes a bit more pleasant:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(comparingByValue(reverseOrder()))
        .collect(toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                (x,y)-> {throw new AssertionError();},
                LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
```

Comment: This answer is the only valid one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I could use this Comparator.reverserOrder().
In fact I thought that would exist a direct way to do this, like

    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValueReverse())

Answer (score 6):

You can pass whatever Comparator you wish to `comparingByValue`.

For example (I hope I got the syntax right, since I can't test it):

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((v1,v2)->v2.compareTo(v1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

By comparing the values of the two entries in the opposite order, using the natural ordering (`Comparable`'s `compareTo`), you get a reversed order compared to what `comparingByValue()` (which is equivalent to `comparingByValue((v1,v2)->v1.compareTo(v2))`) will give you.

BTW, I'm not sure that `Collectors.toMap` returns a `LinkedHashMap` instance, and even if it currently does, it can change in the future, since the Javadoc doesn't mention it, so you can't rely on it.

To make sure that the resulting Map would be a LinkedHashMap, you should use a different variant of toMap :

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((v1,v2)->v2.compareTo(v1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (v1,v2)->v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: As its name indicates (`comparingByValue`), the type parameters of the lambda expression is `V` not `Entry<K,V>` because you provide a comparator on the values, so you might change it to `comparingByValue((v1, v2)->v2.compareTo(v1))` or better use `comparingByValue(reverseOrder())` as @Misha suggested...

Comment: .. and as you said a quick look at the source code of `toMap` you'll see that it returns `toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new);`. So basically your implementation won't do something very useful (although you took it from the OP's question)...

Comment: @AlexisC. Thanks for the comment. I totally missed that. That's what happens when I write code without trying to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

Stream has as `sorted` method which accepts a comparator hence you can directly use the comparator as `(x,y)->y.getKey().compareTo(x.getKey())` for descending sorting.
To sort the map in ascending we can reverse the ordering as `(x,y)->x.getKey().compareTo(y.getKey())`

for consolidating result back into LinkedHashMap we can use Collectors `toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, Supplier<M> mapSupplier)` which 
Returns a Collector that accumulates elements into a Map whose keys and values are the result of applying the provided mapping functions to the input elements.

**Working code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>(); 
            hashMap.put(1,5);
            hashMap.put(7,9);
            hashMap.put(3,8);
            hashMap.put(10,5);

            Function<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>,Integer> keyMapper = x->x.getKey();
            Function<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>,Integer> valueMapper = x->x.getValue();
            BinaryOperator< Integer> mergeFunction = (x,y)->x;// we do not want any merging here 
            Supplier<LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>> mapRequired =()-> {return new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();};// to maintain order we must use LinkedHashMap
            Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> descendingComparator = (x,y)->y.getKey().compareTo(x.getKey());
            // we can write it as  

        System.out.println(
                  hashMap.entrySet().stream()
                             .sorted (descendingComparator) 
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                      keyMapper,
                                                       valueMapper,
                                                       mergeFunction,
                                                       mapRequired)
                                           )
                );           

// or even by writing below will also work

        System.out.println(
                  hashMap.entrySet().stream()
                             .sorted ((x,y)->y.getKey().compareTo(x.getKey())) 
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                       x->x.getKey(),
                                                       x->x.getValue(),
                                                       (x,y)->x,
                                                       LinkedHashMap::new)
                                           )
                );           
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.8
[java.util.Comparator.reversed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--)

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: this is not correct;should be Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))

Comment: doesn't compile

Comment: This will not compile