# Sort Map<String, Long> by value reversed

Tags: sorting, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, Long> map` which I want to sort by the `Long` value in reversed order using the features of Java 8. With Google I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java/22132422) which provides this solution

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(comparing(Entry::getValue))
                     .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                              (e1,e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If I want to have the order reversed in the comments it says to use `comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed()` instead of `comparing(Entry::getValue)`.

However, the code doesn't work. But with this little adaption it does:

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                      (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Do I have to do some imports first to be able to run the original code?

What still remains to get the reversed order, since

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                      (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

gives my an error message:

```
The type Map.Entry does not define getValue(Object) that is applicable here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a LinkedHashMap by value in decreasing order in java stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860667/how-to-sort-a-linkedhashmap-by-value-in-decreasing-order-in-java-stream)

Comment: @Misha I think this thread is more appropriated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205309/misunderstanding-about-comparator-in-java-8. The problem here is that the type does not propagates well with `Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed()` (although your solution in the thread you linked will work and is better).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883991/2711488), the type inference of Java 8 hit its limit when you *chain* method invocations like in `Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed()`.

In contrast, when using *nested* invocations like in `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))` it will work.

Of course, you can use `static` `import`s:

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(reverseOrder(comparing(Entry::getValue)))
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
          (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

but it should be noted that the compiler likes to provide misleading error messages when you forget an `import static` statement (i.e. the method can’t be found) and combine it with lambda expressions or method references.

---

As a final note, there are also the existing comparator implementations [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--) and [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-) which allow you to use

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(reverseOrder(comparingByValue()))
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
          (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

or

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparingByValue(reverseOrder()))
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
          (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```