# Java 8 - Sort Map by value and collect results

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to sort a Map by it's values using JDK 8 style functions. Though I got the sorting part, I'm not sure how to collect the results in a TreeMap. Can someone explain how to get this done in declarative style?

I need to collect to another `Map<String, String>`.

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("John", "time3");
    map.put("Henry", "time6");
    map.put("Smith", "time1");
    map.put("Rock", "time2");
    map.put("Ryan", "time5");
    map.put("Gosling", "time4");

   map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue().reversed())
            ;
```

Comment: Collecting into a `TreeMap` is pointless since it will not preserve the sorted order but will itself sort by the key.  You will need to collect into a map that preserves the order of mappings like a `LinkedHashMap`.  See [How to sort a LinkedHashMap by value in decreasing order in java stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29860667/3920048).

Comment: Thanks @misha. I was able to solve it using LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Though there were couple of questions similar to this, I explicitly wanted to store the results in a Map. Here is the solution.

```
    Map<String, String> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```